# How to connect lavalier microphone with 3.5 jacks into XLR/TRS (using a converter)?

Tags: microphone, portable-recorder, lavalier, xlr, connector

I have two lav microphones, Audio-Technica ATR3350, that have 3.5mm (1/8) mini-jacks

I am looking at Tascam DR60 Mk2 that has 2 XLR/TRS combo ports for input.

Could I use 1/8 to 1/4 adapters on the microphones and then plug them on the XLR/TRS ports? Will that work?

I don't want to buy extra microphones with XLR inputs and all recorders I find that have more than 1 input ports are always XLR (and not mini-jacks)

Comment: There was a related question some time ago: http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/35798/trs-3-5mm-microphone-not-working-in-mixer/35813#35813

Comment: Hmm. Cool, but not the same. I don't have a second adapter to XLR like he has. My setup is 3.5mm -> 1/4 -> TRS/XLR combo. Or maybe I missed something. And that question has no accepted answer as well. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: True - I think the OP bailed on the question :-/ What model is your lav mic?

Comment: Audio-Technica ATR3350. I have two of them because they are so cheap. I have looked at XLR lav mics and they are out of my budget. This is why I am asking the question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to wire an adapter yourself, you can do it this way (it will not be a balanced connection though).

1. Shield to XLR male Pin 1 (Ground)
2. White wire goes to XLR male Pin 2 (Signal)
3. Bridge XLR male Pin 3 to XLR Pin 1 (Ground)

**Important!**
Do *not* send phantom power to the microphone (it will damage it!)!
Use the inline power pack with battery to power the microphone.

You should also be able to use an adapter like the Rode VXLR:
[image]

Just remember: NO PHANTOM POWER ;-) Use the battery option..