# Connecting a 3.5mm Microphone on headset (Logitech G230) to a mixer (Behringer 1202)

Tags: microphone, mixing, mixer

So I have two of these [Logitech G230 Headsets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BFOEY4I), and I want to connect them to my Behringer 1202 mixer. I'm using it for commentary during gameplay for Super Smash Bros. Melee for our tournaments. I heard from someone that connecting it to a DI Box would be good but I'm not too sure if that really works or not.

Please help!

Comment: Super old, but this is what you're after: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/35798/trs-3-5mm-microphone-not-working-in-mixer

Answer (score 1):

The headset microphone needs plug-in-power (sometimes shortened to pip). The most convenient way I know of is to get a XLR phantom power to pip connector. The lowest price I know of is the Rode VXLR+ (Note: the VXLR without plus does not deliver power to the microphone and does not help). The mixer outputs 48 V phantom, the plug converts it to the pip voltage (around 5 V or so) and passes through the mic signal.

And no, a normal DI box will not help.

There are probably alternatives out there on the net. The microphone needs a few volts of power to work, as given to it from the pip system. You could build a box to do that quite easily: it takes only a battery and a few cheap and simple components. If you search the typical Chinese web pages for electronics, it ought to show up.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest method would be using an adapter from 3.5 to 1/4 jack like this one [http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41uY1MBNcAL.*SY300*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41uY1MBNcAL._SY300_.jpg)

The tricky stuff is that the headset outputs it's mic in stereo, even if it's mono so you might get some artefacts. I'm using an berry mixer (qx1002) with this type of converter to capture foot stomps and beats and it works great for this application

Comment: Tried this, nothing comes out. I think the problem is that it's not getting any power at all, so I was wondering if there was a way to externally power the headset without phantom power.

Comment: Downvote -- the answer probably assumes uses another type of microphone, not requiring PIP.