# What sort of device would I need to manage inputs and outputs from multiple computers?

Tags: microphone, mixer

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQPct.jpg) of what I'm trying to do. In my research it seems like a sound mixer will handle the audio from the computers and TV so I can have some or all of them going to the headset. I haven't found much on having the microphone from the headset going back to the computers. Is that possible? Having to toggle a switch on a mixer to send it to one or the other is fine.

Also, the laptops have a single port for both input and output. I presume I can use some adapter to deal with that though, right?

Comment: Can you correct the title of your post please ? Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a mixer with two `AUX sends`, like this [EURORACK
UB1204-PRO](http://www.music-group.com/Categories/Behringer/Mixers/Analog-Mixers/UB1204-PRO/p/P0159):

[image]

This will allow you to route a signal back to the computers. One would be AUX 1 and the other AUX 2. From any channel on the mixer you can control how much is going back to the AUX'es. You should use the `Line In` on the computer when connecting this way.

You may need to find an adapter for the headset microphone to work in the mixer, or get an XLR based microphone (which most likely will sound much better anyway).

Important: Check out [this question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/35798/trs-3-5mm-microphone-not-working-in-mixer/35813#35813) about using headsets with mixers.

Comment: Thanks! AUX sends was the technical word I was missing in my googling.

Answer (score 1):

Michael is correct that a mixer will handle the "magic" but you will have to check on the combination input/output ports on the computers. Some are designed to handle headphones with a mic ([TRRS](http://www.ibroadcastnetwork.org/blog/ts-trs-trrs-balanced-and-unbalanced)) and others are either input or output (TRS) with internal switching, but NOT both at the same time. You'll have to verify which type you have from the manufacturer.

If they are single use only you'll need something like [this](http://www.music-group.com/Categories/Behringer/Computer-Audio/Audio-Interfaces/LINE-2-USB/p/P0BBP/Features#LINE-2-USB) to allow input from the mixer and use the on-board jack for output.

Comment: Good to know. I'll check that out.